# Reading XML contents through LINQ to Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, html-select

I am binding the XML contents to a Dropdownlist in MVC4. From the [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/reading-xml-file-through-linq-a-few-tips/), I tried reading the contents of the XML file. The Where clause in the code returns Object is not reffered to the instance of the object.
Without the where condition the xml contents are read from the file. I want to display only the values based on the capitals ID=1.
**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<State>
<Capital ID="1" CountryName="India">
    <city name="Andaman and Nicobar Islands" value="AN"></city>
    <city name="Andhra Pradesh" value="AP"></city>
</Capital>  
<Capital ID="2" CountryName="USA">
    <city name="Alabama" value="AL"></city>
    <city name="Alaska" value="AK"></city>
</Capital>  
</State>
```

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Details()
{
 string UserID = 12345;
 string partnerid = XCWERT;
 var file = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), "States.xml");            
 var model = new CheckoutModel
 {    
  States =
  from unit in XDocument.Load(file).Document.Elements("State").Elements("Capital").Elements("city") -- This loads all the values
  //   from unit in XDocument.Load(file).Document.Descendants("Capital").Where(unit => (string)unit.Attribute("ID").Value == "1") -- where condition is not accepting and throwing error
   select new SelectListItem
  {
    Text = unit.Attribute("name").Value,
    Value = unit.Attribute("value").Value,                      
  }                     
};
 SelectList selectList = new SelectList(model.States, "Value", "Text");
 ViewData["StateOptions"] = selectList;          
 return View(GetShippingAddress(UserID, partnerid));
 }
```

**View**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("State", ViewData["StateOptions"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "(Select one)", new { @class = "TextBoxBorder" })
```

What is the mistake in my code. ?
Any suggesstions will be greatly helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this

```
var result = XDocument.Load(fileName)
                .Descendants("Capital")
                .First(c => (string)c.Attribute("ID") == "1")
                .Descendants("city")
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    Text = (string)c.Attribute("name"),
                    Value = (string)c.Attribute("value"),
                })
                .ToList();
```